# How often do Snorlax appear in Pokemon X/Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, pokemon-sixth-generation

I failed to catch Snorlax the first time I met him in Route 7. Then after finishing the game, I was happen to pass by a sleeping Snorlax again in Route 7 (on the same bridge), but once again I failed to catch it.

How often do Snorlax appear on that bridge?

**More info:** Ever since I posted this question, I've been coming back to the bridge almost daily for a few weeks, but I haven't seen him again. So in total I've only seen Snorlax on that bridge twice, and I'm thinking that there's some sort of trigger that causes me to see him the second time.

Comment: My guess would be once a day, similar to other daily events such as Mewtwo, the battle with Serena etc

Comment: It has only been about 14 hours since I saw him, but the day *changed*. I'll come back again after 24 hours and see if he's there.

Comment: I believe my previous statement is wrong, the trigger is probably defeating the Elite Four. Have you re-defeated the Elite Four?

Comment: @Robotnik I haven't. I'll do that when I have time and report back.

Comment: @Robotnik Confirmed, Snorlax appeared again after I re beat Elite 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With help of people in the thread, I tried a few things. Just waiting around will not make him reappear.

What will make Snorlax reappear in the bridge is to beat Elite 4. If you want it to appear again, simply go to Pokemon League and re beat the Elite 4.

---

This will apparently also work with other Pokemons like Mewtwo and Zapdos if you failed to catch them (thanks, scenia).

Comment: This applies to all stationary Pokémon in X/Y. Those include Snorlax, Mewtwo, Zygarde and Articuno/Zapdos/Moltres (whichever one appears on your save) once you sent it to the Sea Spirit's Den.

Comment: @scenia Ah, I didn't know that! Are you saying I can get more than 1 MewTwo?

Comment: No, you can only catch each of these once. But if you defeat them or run instead of catching them, they will reappear after you defeat the elite four (again).

Comment: Got it. Did you test them? I still haven't caught Mewtwo and Zapdos.

Comment: I haven't tested them, but the Internet is full of references to this behavior and the official pokedex also mentions something along those lines.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to catch Snorlax (both on the bridge on route 7). The first is when you have to go to Parfum Palace and get the Poke flute. But after you have defeated the Elite-Four (includes times after your first completion of the game), he will reappear on the bridge and go to sleep. When you revisit this area, you will be able to battle him as you did the first time.

Comment: So in total he will only appear twice, is it?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo yes. As I have tested.

Comment: I've tested this a bit more. I can make Snorlax reappear again by beating Elite 4 again. So this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo I have changed the answer to fit this. Thankyou!

Comment: This is still wrong. You can only catch it once. As long as you defeat it or run, it will keep reappearing each time you beat the Elite Four, but once you catch it, it's gone.

Answer (score 2):

That snorlax will appear on the bridge until you catch him, after beating the elite 4 he will reappear anyway. My friend noticed this with his game too. I thought it was weird since I caught it the first time around. So just wait a day and try it again until you capture it, or set the date on your ds to a different day to do it faster.

Comment: Hmm I've been coming back to that bridge daily for a few weeks now, but  I haven't met him again.

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo - I imagine that the trigger is defeating the Elite Four. Have you re-defeated the Elite Four and seeing if he spawned again?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo - yeah my friend did not get it to spawn back until after he beat the Elite Four

Comment: Setting the date or changing to a different 3DS is generally a bad idea. This resets all time-based events and you'll have to wait 24 hours + whatever time is left until that day ends for events bound to specific days (such as daily Berry giveaways or the Inverse Battle) to happen again.